# "Error in parsing package" Android HTC Explorer 2.3.5

Tags: android, gradle, package, android-min-sdk

Currently i migrate my eclipse project into studio but after that when i'm try to test my sign apk in 2.3.5 mobile device it showing me the parse package error.

I know there is a lot of blogs available for how to resolve this problem and many questions related to this on stack too but nothing is work for me.

> What i have tried already

1) I have check my all module's gradle and there is no mistake in module, below is the my app gradle.

2)clear data of playstore app and uninstall all updates as well factory reset my htc device too

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stackoverflow"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 7
    versionName "7.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "ABC V " + defaultConfig.versionName);
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
aaptOptions {
    useNewCruncher false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':hellochartslibrary')
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile project(':CustomBrowser-release-aar')
}
```

I don't know what is the exact problem does it mipmap problem or it's gradle issue any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.